# How to set Exim with TLS on a server with several domains?

Tags: security, ssl, exim

I have a Debian Linux server with Exim.

I want this server to use TLS when sending emails to supporting SMTP hosts, if a email is created by software on my server (for example with `mail` or `sendmail` command or with PHP API for sending emails). Exim should cipher the message even when the sending command or program does not explicitly support TLS.

To make the task more difficult, there is several domains on the site (all having the same IP), but only one SSL certificate (used currently by a Web server for one of the domains only).

So, what to do?